# import resource in ReactJs file fails

Tags: reactjs

Today I started learning React and I am having a hard time with the following problem:

If I append the line

```
> import {logo} from './img/mylogo.png';
```

to my js file I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

It seems that I am unable to use the import statement under any circumstances. Everything works fine without the import statement except for the fact that I am unable to import my image.

What am I missing?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: it should be `import logo from './img/mylogo.png';` If you are using [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files).

Comment: It still does not work without the brackets. I tried both ways

Comment: Check your webpack config this might be configuration problem

Comment: Do you use webpack ? If true please attach your config.

Comment: No, should I? I've never heard of it, I'm more of a backend coder :)

Comment: How did you generate your project? Did you use create-react-app from FB? If not I suggest you try. There's an import logo statement from the generated App.js and it works.